# What is the Star Trek episode where aliens from another dimension are sent to our dimension when they die?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

I am wracking my brain for this episode.  I think it was a *Next Generation* episode, but I can't find it on the list of their episodes.  The ship comes across a small vessel which contains an alien from another dimension.  The alien was supposed to be dead, since it is a funeral vessel, but he is still alive.

The alien starts to question his faith, since our dimension is obviously not Heaven.  The "funeral vessels" are all crashed on an asteroid or moon, however.  In the end, it is found that the moon has some strange electromagnetic field that may be a result of the energy from the other dead aliens.  So perhaps that moon is a form of heaven for them.

The episode did a good job of exploring issues of death and the afterlife.  I was hoping to share it with a trekkie friend who just lost a loved one.  Please help if you can remember it.

Comment: I don't think that trying to convince your friend that Heaven's fake would cheer him up...

Comment: I think you mean well, but please give your friend some time to process and grieve first. Trying to show or discuss this episode with them in an attempt to help them will likely be confusing and seem insensitive or offensive.

Comment: algiogia: The episode certainly implies that there may exist an afterlife of sorts for those aliens.

Comment: @HamSandwich Yes, but only at the very end, almost as an afterthought.

Comment: Of course. Spiritual things are usually limited in Star Trek. I think there's a deleted scene from "Who Watches the Watchers" floating around where Captain Picard phasers a few dozen of the Mintakans after finding out that they want to turn him into a god.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I agree that grieving takes time.  There is no way to "cheer anyone up" after the loss of a partner of 17 years.  I was thinking it might help him at some point though.  I would also like to watch it again myself, since his partner was my friend as well (not to mention all of my other friends and family that have been kicking off lately).  The moral of the episode is not that "heaven is fake," but that an afterlife may exist is some form that we don't completely understand.  Does anyone remember the name or series for this episode?

Answer (score 54):

The episode you're thinking of is from Star Trek: Voyager and is called [Emanations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Emanations_(episode)).

Excerpt from Act 1:

> Chakotay reports that they have discovered eighteen bodies on the
>   asteroid – eleven male, seven female. The bodies are in various stages
>   of decomposition, some have been there for years, others just a few
>   days.

Excerpt from Act 2:

> Kim learns that when the species, called the Vhnori, are near death,
>   they are placed in a coffin-like device called a cenotaph, which
>   euthanizes the occupant, then transports them to the "Next Emanation,"
>   their culture's concept of Heaven or nirvana.

Excerpt from Act 4:

> Kim's presence disturbs the plans of Hatil Garan, whose family has
>   convinced him that it is time to be sent to the Next Emanation.
>   Expressing his doubts to his wife, Loria, she angrily tells Kim to
>   leave her husband alone.

Excerpt from Act 5:

> Janeway tells him that may not be the whole story, as the energy that
>   was detected by Voyager had slight neural energy emissions from the
>   newly appearing bodies, adding to a complex and dynamic energy field
>   that inundated the asteroid field and surrounded the planet – a
>   possible indication of the Next Emanation.

Comment: That's on an asteroid, not a vessel. It also isn't from a different dimension, transport happens through a subspace vacuole within our own realm. On top of that, the first Vhnori to walk around Voyager arrived dead, not alive. She was supposed to be dead, was dead and was resurrected (not uncommon in the Star Trek universe with humans which have been dead less than a day or two). So, while this episode is similar, Brian may well have been thinking of a completely different one.

Comment: @Mast Memory is a generally faulty thing. Do you have a better proposal?

Comment: @Mast Emanations is definitely the correct answer, question just got a few of the details confused. Emanations is a good match, and no other Star Trek episode even comes close. Ben Hocking, maybe the Act Five reference to the energy emissions to strengthen the case?

Comment: I would definitely guess this as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  That was the episode I was thinking of.  Looking forward to watching it again.

Comment: @Drew — I added the Act Five reference.

Comment: @Mast — As others have mentioned, memory is often faulty on these things. I didn't find this by just searching, but because I remembered this episode similarly as Brian.

Comment: well. to be fair to @BrianHaney - this was a better episode when it was called "Half a Life" on TNG ;)

Comment: @BrianHaney - Don't forget to click the "accepted" button (on the left of the question) to show that this is the right answer

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that when you can't remember an episode from Star Trek it tends to be from Voyager?  Roddenberry's Razor?